# Unable to start monit

Tags: 16.04, init.d, monit

I want to use `monit` in a container to schedule some scripts to be executed as scheduled but am unable to start it. I've  added `/etc/init.d/monit start` into the container's start file but still can't get it started. Here's what I get:

```
root@ee48c7f:/# monit -t
Control file syntax OK
root@ee48c7f:/# /etc/init.d/monit start
 * Starting daemon monitor monit                                               [ OK ] 
root@ee48c7f:/# /etc/init.d/monit status
 * monit is not running
root@ee48c7f:/# ps ax | grep monit
18065 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto monit
root@ee48c7f:/#
```

The container is based on a `Ubuntu xenial image`. I'm not sure how I can find out why it doesn't start and keep running. `dmesg` doesn't seem to give any hints. There is a `/var/log/monit.log` but it is and stays 0B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add at least the

```
start daemon 30
```

command to `/etc/monit/monitrc` in order for it to start properly.